# How to use AND (&) operator in Pandas between 2 filters?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am using the StackOverflow annual survey data to do a sample data analysis project. The data can be found in the below link:
[Annual Data Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019)

I want to filter 2 columns using a single command. The two data type of 2 columns are as follows:

```
Country                 88751 non-null  object
ConvertedComp           55823 non-null  float64
```

I want to select a list of countries and then see if their ConvertedComp is greater than 10000.

To make a list of required countries i am using the following filter:

```
countries = ['United States', 'India','United Kingdom','Germany']
filt = (df['Country'].isin(countries) )
```

I am using the following filter on the ConvertComp as follows:

```
filt1 = (df['ConvertedComp']>1000 )
```

I want to use both these conditions to make a single filter in a single cell. I am using the & operator as follows:

```
filter1 = (df['Country'].isin(countries) & df['ConvertedComp']>1000)
```

According to my understanding, when i apply the above filter to the dataframe, I should not see any countries except the ones mentioned in the above list. However when I apply the filer the dataframe is giving me 0 results.

Can anyone please explain how to correctly use the & operator while using filters?

Comment: probably operator precedence... have you tried: `filter1 = (df['Country'].isin(countries)) & 
 (df['ConvertedComp']>1000)` ?

Comment: It's generally easier to use the callable methods when in doubt, so for two conditions... `filter1 = df['Country'].isin(countries) & df['ConvertedComp'].gt(1000)` for instance